# Add a filter/rule for outgoing emails in Outlook 365

Tags: email, office365, rule

I'm using Office365. I need to forward automatically all the emails sent to another email address. I've looked in the "Rules options" (filter) but it seems that allow only to filter the ingoing mail.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add your self as a recipient to the outgoing emails (as CCed or BCCed) and apply the rules.